# Observable for http calls with certain action on each timeout

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

My strategy for http calls currently looks like this:
Timeout each request after 10s, and retry the call for max. 5 times.
As far as I can tell I somewhat figured this out, it seems to work:

```
this.httpClient.post(url, body)
  .timeout(10000)
  .retryWhen(error => {
    return error.delay(500).take(5);
  })
.subscribe(
  response => {
    // stuff
  },
  error => {
    // stuff
  }
```

Now my problem is that I'd need to do something when every timeout occurs (e.g. just print a short info text 'timeout 1', 'timeout 2'...).

How do I do this?

Currently at rxjs 5.4.2 with Angular 4.2.4 (shouldn't matter, I guess).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is add [do operator](https://gist.github.com/btroncone/d6cf141d6f2c00dc6b35#do)

```
error.delay(500).do(() => {console.log('try')}).take(5);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `timeout` operator emits an `error` notification so if you want to be able to perform a side-effect you can use `do`.

Be aware that `do` takes three arguments for `next`, `error` and `complete` notification respectively so the correct way to use it for you is like this:

```
this.httpClient.post(url, body)
  .timeout(10000)
  .do(null, error => console.log(error) /* ... or whatever */)
  .retryWhen(error => {
    return error.delay(500).take(5);
  })
  ...
```